# HTTP Request Condition

Tags: javascript, web-services, servlets

Is it possible to set a condition on the HTTP request at page refresh. I have a webpage that refreshes every 60secs..If the HTTP response is anything but "202"  ; Section 10.2.3: Accepted then do not refresh.

We want to keep our user from ever seeing a 404 page upon a refresh. Its preferred to have a client side solution if possible.

Comment: Check it with AJAX first? What are you doing to refresh the page every 60 seconds? And why are you doing it?

Comment: I have a dynamic datatable that needs to be refreshed. We are currently refreshing it by   HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Refresh","40")

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a HEAD request to the page. This would test if what you want is available without having to retrieve all of the information that a GET would. On the success of the HEAD request, do your actual page refresh.